# Where 2 != 2 in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

This is driving me nuts, I have:

```
$listingUserId = $this->Photo->Listing->field('user_id');
$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
if($listingUserId != $userId) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__("User ID $userId did not match listing user ID    $listingUserId or listing does not exist"));
      return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'listings','action' => 'index'));
}
```

It should be 2 and 2, the database content confirms that the user_id field is populated.
So I check what is inside the vars, modifying the code to:

```
$listingUserId = $this->Photo->Listing->field('user_id');
$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
die("$listingUserId and $userId");
if(...
```

I get the output:

```
2 and 2
```

What is going on? Some "quantum mechanics" effect?  When observing the var contents they are equal when not observing the contents they are not equal?

Var_dump gives:

```
string '2' (length=1)
string '2' (length=1)
```

Comment: Try `var_dump`'ing them to see what the types are.

Comment: You should check the content with either `var_dump` or `debug` instead of printing them within `die()`.

Comment: Are you saying that the if statement is evaluating to true ($listingUserId does not equal $userID and that it's running `$this->Session->setFlash(__("User ID $userId did not match listing user ID    $listingUserId or listing does not exist"));`

Comment: @trafalgar You are definitely making some kind of mistake. The code is fine, and from the debug output the values coming in, as well. You are probably confused somewhere. Try to take a look at it after a break.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Going to the cinema to watch Interstellar now...

Comment: @trafalgar , You should not post **PRIVATE Info.** like where are you going etc. here.

Answer (score -1):

It may possible one of your variable is of type string and other is integer. 2!=2 this will return false So your code will execute else block.